# Is it correct to say: "she's having her housework done by this evening"

Tags: prepositions, time

I'm not sure about the correct phrase to say something that has to end before a specific moment. I read that it can be written as: "by + expire time/date". For instance, you can think about doing an essay that has a duty time: "you have to hand in this essay by the 16th of March/by the end of this month". Is it wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: If I "have my housework done" it implies someone else is going to do it for me, which doesn't sound like what you mean?

Comment: Of course, I agree with you. However I made two different examples to explain better my aim: understand if it is correct to say, "by + expression of time", when an activity or something else is going to finish before or exactly  at a certain time.

Comment: The time factor is independent of who does the work.  I just want to be clear if the work has to be done by *her* or if she's having someone else do it.

Comment: she's having someone else doing it.

Comment: "by + time/date" is correct (like "I have to leave *by five o'clock*" or "the dam will be finished *by Friday*"), but your example about the housework sounds strange to me.  I think it's because the present continous (*is having*) doesn't really fit with *by (time)*.  Firstly, I think a future tense would work better: she **will** have the housework done...  Secondly, when I hear "is having it done by..." the next thing I expect to hear is *who* is doing it, not *when* it will be done by, so it makes me do a double-take and go back and reinterpret the sentence.

Comment: thanks for your clear answer. For the first thing, if I write: 
"a cleaner is going to her home this afternoon. She's having her housework done by this evening", will present continuous as future tense be correct? I'm considering it as a thing arranged between people for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You have to hand in this essay by the 16th of March.

This is grammatically correct and easily understandable.

> She's having her housework done by this evening

This doesn't really work. The **by** is fine, but the use of present continuous doesn't work with it. You normally use present continuous about something that is happening now, or something that is happening **around** some specified time in the future, for example:

> She's having her housework done **now**
>   She's having her housework done **this evening**

You can't really use it for **before** a specified time. For that, you should use future perfect:

> She **will have had** her housework done by this evening.

With present perfect, the by-time is not only possible but required, so this takes precedence over the optional by-agent clause that might be expected after the passive-voice **having ... done**. This therefore deals with the double-take issue raised by stangdon in his comment.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this sentence is that it's easy to get confused by two overlapping constructions:

> She's having her housework done = someone else is doing it
>
> She'll have her housework done by this evening = she will finish by this evening.

Because of this confusion, if you need to imply that someone else is doing it **and** that it'll be done by this evening, then it's best to be verbose:

> She's having her housework done, and they will be finished by this evening.